# Converting StringDate to a queryable representation. Group and project sum of today,yesterday, week, month

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was about to try to figure out how to complete the given question.

It might consists of 2 parts, first one being - my collection dates are stored in plain string with a mysql format (YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss), the second how to project the (today, yesterday, 7 day, month - summaries).

I have been experimenting around and this is what I came up with.

Pipe 1.

$match - nothing fancy there just a simple field = value.

Pipe 2.

$addField - trying to process the string date as a ISO date I believe? I am not sure

```
{
  expired: {
    $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$expired',
            timezone: 'America/New_York'
    }
  }
}
```

Pipe 3.

$match - Quoted out wanted to select only a specific range so not more than 30 days - doesn't work

```
 expired: {
                $gt: ISODate(new Date(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*30)))
            }
```

Pipe 4.

$group - Here I group and sum everything per day. So an output is

> _id: 2021-09-27, theVal : 100

```
{
  _id: { 
    $dateToString: { 
      date: { $toDate: "$expired" }, 
      format: "%Y-%m-%d" } 
  },
  theVal : {$sum:{$first:"$values.quantity"}} // as $values is an array [0].quantity,[1].quantity,[2].quantity - I am just interested in the first element.
}
```

Pipe 5.

$project - getting rid of the _id field - making it date name field, keeping theVal.

```
{
  "date": "$_id",
  "theVal": 1,
  "_id": 0
}
```

theVal is a sum of integers within a day.

Questions

- Between Pipe 1 and 2 ( temporary 3 ) I should be able to match dates
  within the last 30 days to reduce the processing?
- How to get a desired output like this:

  ```
   {
       today : 100,
       yesterday : 10,
       7days : 220,
       month: 1000,
   }
  ```

Really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to "replicate" what you intend to do as you didn't provided sample test data.

You may want to do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` : filter out the ids you want - same as your pipe 1
2. `$dateFromString`: use `"format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "timezone": "America/New_York"`
3. `$match` : filter out records that are within 30 days with `$expr` and `$$NOW`
4. `$group` : group by date without time; achieved by converting to dateString with date part only
5. `$addFields` : project flags that determine if the record are within `today`, ``yesterday`,` 7days`,` month`
6. `$group` : As you didn't provided what is the meaning of `today`, ``yesterday`,` 7days`,` month`, I made an assumption that they are the cumulative sum in the ranges. Simply and conditional` $sum` will do the summation with the help of flags in step 5

Here is a [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bxpFaqoLfPn) for your reference.